# Replace only the first matching line while preserving leading whitespace

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file which having the sentence:

```
"cutoffTime": "20151024000000"
```

I would like to use sed or grep to find the line starts with `cutoffTime` , 
then replace the whole line with another string, for example:

```
"startTime" : "20151028000000"
```

---

*Editor's note:*

Two *additional requirements* have emerged *after* the question - and several answers - were first posted, and the title *now* reflects them:

- *Preserve leading whitespace* (or at least tabs) at the beginning of the line to replace.
- Only replace the *first* matching line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **preserve leading whitespace** at the beginning of the line:

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*\)"cutoffTime":.*$/\1"startTime" : "20151028000000"/' file
```

- `^\([[:blank:]]*\)` captures any mix of spaces and tab, if present, at the beginning of the line and prepends it to the replacement line (via `\1`, the reference to the first (and only) capture group in the regex, in effect preserving the leading whitespace from the original line.

To **also replace only the *first* match**: the complexity of the solution depends on the `sed` implementation used:

<sup>Note that in both solutions below the form `//` (`s//`) - i.e., *omitting* the regular expression - means that the most recently applied regular expression is implicitly reused.</sup>

- *GNU* `sed`:

```sh
sed '0,/^\([[:blank:]]*\)"cutoffTime":.*$/ s//\1"startTime" : "20151028000000"/' file
```

`0,/.../` is a *GNU* `sed` extension that allows the regex to *terminate* the range even if it matches the very *first* line (which using `1` wouldn't do, because it would invariably *start* the range at the 1st line, and then only start looking for the regex on *subsequent* lines). In effect, this limits the range to the beginning of the file through the 1st occurrence of the regex, wherever it occurs, and only replaces that occurrence.

- A POSIX-features-only `sed` such as *BSD* `sed` (also used on OS X):

```sh
replacement='"startTime" : "20151028000000"'
sed -e '1 s/^\([[:blank:]]*\)"cutoffTime":.*$/\1'"$replacement"'/; t' \
    -e '1,// s//\1'"$replacement"'/' file
```

Since the `0,/.../` feature is not part of POSIX, the case where the match could be on the *first* line must be handled separately, so the above first only looks on line `1` for a match and substitutes; `1,//` then effectively looks from line 2 until the first subsequent match and substitutes. Note that the `t` call after the first substitution ends the script cycle *if a substitution was performed*, which means that range `1,//` is then never entered. The net effect is that substitution occurs only for the first occurrence of the regex, wherever that first occurrence is.

Answer (score 2):

According to OPs updated query use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) like this to find and replace only first appearance, as following;

```
sed '0,/^"cutoffTime":.*/{s/^"cutoffTime":.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/}' file
```

This will change the first appeared pattern as prescribed above.

For replacement in source file use `-i`

```
sed -i '0,/^"cutoffTime":.*/{s/^"cutoffTime":.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/}' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed '0,/<pattern>/{s/<pattern>/<replacement>/}' file
```

**Output:**

```
$ sed '0,/^"cutoffTime":.*/{s/^"cutoffTime":.*/"startTime" : "20151028000
000"/}' file1

"startTime" : "20151028000000"
"cutoffTime": "20151024000000"
"cutoffTime": "20151024000000"
```

Comment: The `0,/…/` technique is great for only processing the first match, but it's worth noting that this feature is _GNU_ `sed`-specific; 
also, you can optimize it slightly by using `s//` (emtpy regex in the `s` call) instead of duplicating the regex from the address.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`

```
sed 's/^"cutoffTime":.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/' file
```

and check the result. If you want to modify the original file

```
sed -i .bak 's/^"cutoffTime":.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/' file
```

- The first part of the `s` command performs a substitution of the first expression (`^"cutoffTime":.*`) with the replacement `"startTime" : "20151028000000"`.
- The expression matches the beginning of the line `^` followed by your text `"cutoffTime":` followed by any character (`.`) repeated 0 or more times (`*`)

Comment: Dear Matteo, thank you for your reply. This approach works well when I put cutoffTime as beginning of the line, if I have some tabs before it, it does not work. Can you please help me change it a little bit, means it will find the first appearance of cutoffTime and replace the whole sentence from the position found cutoffTime, with "startTime" : "20151028000000". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When your `sed` doesn't support the -i option, you can use `ed`

```
ed -s request  << EOF
,s/^"cutoffTime":.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/
w
q
EOF
```

EDIT: Changed requirements from OP, new solution below.
You can play around with the substitution string. You can practice the REGEX by using something like `cat request | sed 's/my_practicum/my_solution/'`.
When you do not want to match at the beginning of the line, just remove the special `^`. When you only want to change the first match, you should start with a jump to the correct line. In the solution beneath I will repeat the search-string, so you will not replace anything if you can not find a match.

```
ed -s request  << EOF
/cutoffTime
s/.*cutoffTime.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/
w
q
EOF
```

When you want to preserve leading characters, change the substition line:

```
ed -s request  << EOF
/cutoffTime
s/"cutoffTime.*/"startTime" : "20151028000000"/
w
q
EOF
```

Comment: Dear Walter, thank you for your reply. This approach works well when I put cutoffTime as beginning of the line, if I have some tabs before it, it does not work. Can you please help me change it a little bit, means it will find the first appearance of cutoffTime and replace the whole sentence from the position found cutoffTime, with "startTime" : "20151028000000". Thank you very much.

Comment: You should then edit your question and put all the requirements there.